# Whatever components we connect to the Arduino, their grounds and 5v pin connection must be the same?

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, arduino-motor-shield, raspberrypi, ultrasonics

I am trying to connect different types of sensors & motors to the Arduino should I make their grounds and 5v pins on the same connection.

Comment: If u didn't understand I can explain you

Comment: I understood it now, by the way thanks for asking

Answer (score 1):

All the grounds must be connected. They don't have to be the same physical pin - the Arduino has multiple GND pins, but they are all connected internally.

The 5V doesn't matter where you get that from, as long as it's regulated and the associated ground is connected to all the others.